# Erro ao ler variáve Chr em c

Tags: c, char

Saberiam me dizer porque porque com a linha 0 funciona e com a linha não funciona?
Com a linha 1, ele imprime como abaixo somente 3 caracteres e são caracteres inválidos.

```
char string[100];

gets (string);             //LINE 0
//string[100] = "0730";    //LINE 1

for (i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
   printf ("Caractere %d: %c\n", i, string[i]);
return (0);

//**** impressao
//printf("Horario saida: %s\n",hor_saida);
return 0;
```

'''
`

Comment: tu estás imprimindo um char usando %d...

Answer (score 0):

A String em C funciona como um vetor de caracteres.
No caso, se vocẽ colocar `string[100] = "texto"`, a posição 100 da string (*que no caso seria inexistente, visto que a contagem de posição começa do 0, tendo como posição final o 99, contendo o '/0' neste*) teria o valor atribuido "texto", o qual é inválido.

Não sei exatamente ao certo o que você deseja fazer, como o texto seria obtido, etc. Mas, se você deseja atribuir um texto de outra variável, deveria atribuir caractere a caractere em cada posição. Incluindo o '/0'.

```
int k, i;
char string[100] = "Um texto antes";
char text[] = "Texto depois";//cuidado para não ultrapassar 99 caracteres

//printa antes de substituir
for (int i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
   printf ("Caractere %d: %c\n", i, string[i]);
   
printf("Text: %s\n",text);
printf("String: %s\n",string);
  
printf("\nSubstituindo\n\n");
//substituir
for(k = 0; k < sizeof(text);k++){
    string[k] = text[k];
}
//printa depois de substituir
for (int i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
   printf ("Caractere %d: %c\n", i, string[i]);


printf("Text: %s\n",text);
printf("String: %s\n",string);
return 0;
```